# IP address pattern in SQL like command

Tags: sql-server, ip-address, sql-like

I want to select rows which contains an IP address in a `nvarchar` column. What's the correct `where` statement?

```
SELECT * FROM tblUrl WHERE ... (Url contains an IP address)
```

Comment: This will be much easier if you implement a CLR assembly that allows you to use Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 4):

The "usual way" to encode IP address in Database is either:

- 192.168.001.010 (note the padding "0"s)
  or
- as a integer being (((192 * 256)+ 168 )* 256 + 1 )*256 +10

Both formats allow you to quickly match for an ip in an interval:

```
SELECT * FROM tblURL where URL > "192.168.010.000" and URL < "192.168.011.255"
```

or
    SELECT * FROM tblURL where URL > 3232238080 and URL < 3232239080

If you table `tblUrl` contains URLs as suggested by your question, then you should perform a DNS lookup first to resolve the name into an IP Address.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this

```
SELECT * FROM tblUrl WHERE URL like '192.168.1.%'
```

which will select all ip addresses from 192.168.1.1 to .254

Or you can be more creative such as

```
SELECT * FROM tblUrl WHERE URL like '192.168.1.[0-9][0-9]'
```

this will select all IP addresses 192.168.1.10 to .99

Comment: ***completely rhetorical*** - but, why wouldn't MS see fit to find a way to integrate the power of Regex in SqlServer?

Comment: I have have no clue about any part of IP address. It could be anything!